# What does super(subclass, class).__new__(class) do?

Tags: python, inheritance

In the following `Python` implementation of the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance
```

What does the line `cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)` do?

Among other things in this line that I don't understand is the `super` usage. I saw usage of `super` with `(subclass, instance)`, but here we pass it `(subclass, class)`. So is it going to have `(Singleton class, Singleton class)` as arguments?

[Live example](https://repl.it/repls/AffectionateAdoredFtpclient)

Comment: `cls` **is the instance** in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `super()` is used for two purposes:

- To supply an ordered list of classes to search through; the order is the Method Resolution Order (MRO), and searching for attributes on `super()` starts at the class following the one named as the first argument to `super()`
- To bind any descriptors (like methods) to.

So `super(clsobject, second_argument)` will look for a `__mro__` list, then search for `clsobject`, then continue searching the remainder of the list for the attribute you wanted. It then uses the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) to bind the object to `second_argument`.

The `__new__` method only makes sense on a class, because it creates a new instance; there is no instance yet when that method is called; it is the factory that is supposed to produce the instance for that class.

So you can't pass in an instance as the second argument. You can only pass in a class, and `super()` can handle that. For instances, `super()` looks at `type(instance).__mro__`, but for classes, `classobject.__mro__` is used instead. So passing in `cls` is perfectly fine here.

`__new__` is also a *static method*, meaning that it ignores the binding process. No automatic passing in of the first argument, the class, takes place. You need to do this manually, hence the `...__new__(cls)` call.

So in this specific instance, the line:

```
cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls)
```

will search for `Singleton` in `cls.__mro__`, find the next object with a `__new__` attribute, and then try to bind that `__new__` attribute to `cls`. If you didn't use multiple inheritance, that is going to be `object.__new__`. The `__new__` method is static, so no binding takes place, so you are given `object.__new__`, which is then called with `cls` as the first argument. This produces an instance of the `Singleton` class (or a subclass thereof), which is then assigned to the attribute `instance` on the class object.

Comment: In Python 3, is it safe to do `cls.instance = super().__new__(cls)` here?

Comment: @PM2Ring: yes, because `super()` then finds the `__class__` closure (set to `Singleton`) and the *first* argument to the method, here `cls` (this is always the first name in the code object local names).